# $\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_{1/k}^k f(x)\,dx \neq \int_0^{\infty}f(x)\,dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I am trying to prove that $\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_{1/k}^k f(x)\,dx$  is not always equal to $\int_0^{\infty}f(x)\,dx$, where $\int_0^{\infty}f(x)\,dx=\lim_{R\to0}\lim_{S\to\infty}\int_R^Sf(x)\,dx$.

It seems that there should be a counterexample where $f(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to0$ and $x\to\infty$ with $\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_{1/k}^kf(x)\,dx=0$ but $\int_0^{\infty}f(x)\,dx$ does not exist.

For example, I tried $f(x)=|\ln x|$, but this does not work since then $\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_{1/k}^k f(x)\,dx$ does not exist.

For every example I have tried so far, they are the same. Can anyone suggest how to construct a counterexample?

Comment: For $f(x)=\frac{\log(x)}{x}$, the integral $\int_{1/k}^{k}f(x)\,dx$ equals zero for any $k>0$, but of course $f(x)$ is not integrable over $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another example such that $$\lim_{A\to\infty}\int_{1/A}^Af(x)\,dx\neq\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx.$$
Here $A$ tends to infinity through the real line rather than $\mathbb N$.
Let
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac1x & x\geq1,\\
-\frac1x & 0<x<1.
\end{cases}$$
So $\int_{1/A}^Af(x)\,dx=0$ for $A>1$ but $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx$ does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f$ be any nice continuous function on $[0,1]$ with $f(0)=f(1)$ and $\int_0^{1} f(x) \, dx=0$ but $\int_0^{\frac 1 2} f(x) \, dx\neq 0$. Extend $f$ to a continuous periodic function with period $1$. Then the first limit is $0$ but the second limit does not exist

Comment: Specific example $f(x)=\sin (2\pi x)$.

Comment: Why is $\int_0^{1/2}f(x)\,dx\neq 0$ needed?

Comment: So that $\lim \int_0^{k} f(x)\, dx$ and $\lim \int_0^{k+\frac 1 2} f(x)\, dx$ are different.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a coincidence that $\int_0^\infty f$ does not exist in the two counterexamples given - it's easy to see that if  $\int_0^\infty$ does exist (according to the definition you gave) then it *does* equal $\lim\int_{1/k}^kf$.